# Does "reside" mean to live in a place permanently?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, synonyms

Is the word "reside" synonym of "to live in" ?
I am a student and where i live now is not my permanent address. I googled the meaning of "reside" and it says " have one's permanent home in a particular place."
so can i use the word for temporary living place?

Comment: In the UK, student accommodation blocks are called _halls of residence_, so in this context it seems you can.

Comment: @KateBunting - Nicola Sturgeon has said that people 'ordinarily resident' in Scotland on Day One of independence will be eligible for a Scottish passport, which is why my partner and I are checking house prices in Edinburgh.

Answer (score 1):

"Reside" has a legal meaning.  That legal meaning might vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.  And this isn't the right place to discuss the law.

In the general meaning in English, where you "reside" is where you ordinarily live. For a student, only you can answer this.  Do you ordinarily live at university (but stay at you parents' home during the holidays? For example) Or do you ordinarily live with your parents, but visit the university during term time?

Legally there may be an answer to this question.  But practically only you can decide.  What is "ordinary" for you now that you are at university?